# Monic polynomal $f \in \mathbb{Z}[X]$ such that $f(2)=13$ have at most three distinct roots in $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: polynomials, roots

how can I show that given a monic polynomial $f \in \mathbb{Z}[X]$ such that  $f(2)=13$ have at most three distinct roots in $\mathbb{Q}$?

I know that these roots has to be in $\mathbb{Z}$, but I don't know how to continue or how to use this.

Comment: You title says _at most_, but your question says _at least_. Which do you mean?

Comment: Oh sorry! I mean "at most"

Comment: Do you mean at most three _distinct_ roots?  Otherwise you can multiply by arbitrary powers of $(X-1)$.

Comment: It's "distinct". Thank you guys, I wrote this question in a rush.

Comment: How do you now that the roots have to be in $\mathbb{Z}$? I’m afraid I don’t see this.

Comment: You can see this using this theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem and the fact that the polynomial is monic

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $f(X)$ has four distinct roots $a,b,c,d$, then $(X-a)(X-b)(X-c)(X-d)$ divides $f(X)$, so $(2-a)(2-b)(2-c)(2-d)$ must divide $f(2)=13$.

But this is impossible, as the product of four distinct integers always has at least two (possibly non-distinct) prime factors.

Comment: How can a product of three distinct integers divides a prime? If I have two distinct integers they have to be $1$ and $13$, but three?

Comment: Oh, now I see, there are triplets like these, for example (1,-1,-13).

Comment: @HaroldF Right, and this lets us conclude that the roots of a degree $3$ polynomial with $f(2)=13$ must be $1,3,15$ or $1,3,-11$.

Comment: Yes, if the roots are rational

Comment: @HaroldF Here is probably a better way to say it: if a polynomial $f$ with integer coefficients has $f(2)=13$, then its rational roots must lie in the set $\{1,3,-11,15\}$, with at most one root in $\{-11,15\}$.  Note that we do not require $f$ to be monic.